Using textures in Principled BSDF - Unable to mask!
I want to get textures from Farming Simulator game for crops in Blender. As you can see in the image below, I have planes that I need to apply these textures to. I have currently applied them in Principled BSDF. Below is the node image.

This is how it appears after I apply the material to the planes.

This is with Cycles renderer. You can see those fuzzy borders around, I need to remove them. There is a 'fmask' texture , I guess it is a glossy map that we can use as mask and get sharp edges, but I am not sure how to do it or even if this is a correct way.

I basically want it to appear like the one in image below:

Could you please help me in setting up the materials to achieve this. Thanks in advance!
Here is the .blend file. 
Fuzziness


Plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture node that has the image called barleyStage04_alpha.dds into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF. The b&w image called barleyStage04_alpha.dds seems to be made to determine where the transparency must be. You'll see the transparency right away in the Rendered preview mode of Cycles, but if you switch to Material preview mode, or if you use Eevee, you need to choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend:

You can control the fuzziness if you put a Converter > ColorRamp between the Image Texture and the Principled BSDF and play with the node needles:


How can I attach the blend file here?

Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload, make sure that you have packed the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Uploaded blend file. Thanks. I tried plugging the alpha as you said, but didn't get sharp edges.

OK I've edited my answer, I hope it's more clear

Thank you. I am able to get the nodes connected. Is there a way to make this fuzziness transparent too? Image at bottom of post above.

@UnrealPanda With the here suggested Blend Mode > Alpha Blend the fuzziness will not go away (at least not without manipulating the alpha map in the shader). Looks like the material is created to be used with Alpha Clip - this way you will get a sharp border depending on the Clip Threshold value. The default is 0.5, meaning each value below is transparent and above it the material is opaque. The default value seems to give a good result, but you can change it to see what you like better.

You can control it if you put a Converter > ColorRamp between the Image Texture and the Principled BSDF, play with node needle until you're satisfied, see my edit

Thank you guys. I am able to get the sharp edges now. :)
